# What can cause SSH login error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtual-machine

I thought `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` is caused by `/etc/hosts.allow` and/or `/etc/hosts.deny`, but allow's only entry is `ALL:ALL` and deny is empty.

On my **Google Cloud VM** I've added:

1. `ALL:ALL` to `\etc\hosts.allow` and `\etc\hosts.deny` is empty
2. A firewall rule setup for the **Google Cloud VM** to allow tcp:2222
3. `GatewayPorts clientspecified` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

From the **destination** (the computer I want to access) to my **Google Cloud VM**:

```
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:2222:localhost:22 -i google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<google vm ip>
```

After that `Netstat -plant 2222` yields:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2700/0
```

Within the **Google Cloud VM**:

```
ssh -p 2222 -i google_compute_engine localhost -v

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file google_compute_engine type -1
debug1: identity file google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

If I remove -p 2222, the `ssh` command connects locally.

Comment: Note that you may see this exact behavior under many circumstances.  I turned off sshd on the target-machine, and still received the same error.  Check your firewall logs and verify the request is reaching the target-machine.